# Cannot Making Radius Exception for Circle Own Exception

Tags: java

the exception cannot appear, I apparently don't know where is the problem. I want to make own exception for circle radius. For example, if my input is negative value, then the exception need to appear. I made 3 classes. TestCircle.java, Circle.java and IllegalRadiusException.java

TestCircle.java

```
package circle;
public class TestCircle {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double newRad;

    try {

        Circle A = new Circle();

        A.InputRadius();
        A.Calculation();
        newRad = A.getRadius();
        A.Result();
    } catch (IllegalRadiusException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Circle.java

```
package circle;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Circle {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private double radius;
private double area;

//this is consturctor method
public Circle() throws IllegalRadiusException {
    if (radius >= 0) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.area = area;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalRadiusException("Radius Cannot be Negative");
    }
}

public void setRadius(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}

public double getRadius() {
    return radius;
}

public void setArea(double area) {
    this.area = area;
}

public double getArea() {
    return area;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------//
public void Calculation() {
    area = 3.142 * radius * radius;
}

public void InputRadius() {
    System.out.print("Radius: ");
    radius = input.nextDouble();

}

public void Result() {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Radius: " + radius);
    System.out.println("Area: " + area);
}
}
```

IllegalRadiusException.java

```
package circle;
public class IllegalRadiusException extends Exception {

//Extra kena tambah 'extends Exception'
//WAJIB KENA LETAK untuk CREATE OWN EXCEPTION
public IllegalRadiusException() {

    super();

}

public IllegalRadiusException(String message) {

    super(message);
}
}
```

Comment: And where are you setting the value for the circle's radius, in your main method?

Comment: value for radius is input.. we have to put input for the radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the constructor would be called only once, at the time of object's instantiation. 
You've added the check for exception, only in this constructor.

For your example to work as needed, you need to throw exceptions from your *InpurRadius* method too, if the user enters an invalid value.

---

Change your method to this.

```
public void InputRadius() throws IllegalRadiusException {
    System.out.print("Radius: ");
    double entered_radius = input.nextDouble();
    if (entered_radius >= 0) {
        this.radius = entered_radius;
        this.area = area;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalRadiusException("Radius Cannot be Negative");
    }

}
```

Comment: I put IllegalRadiusException but it appears 'catch clause' for both of them

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Thats works! What if triangle? There are 2 sides. If side1 is wrong input, exception says "side1 wrong input". If side2 is wrong input, "side2 wrong input". If side1 and side2 wrong, "side1 and side2 wrong input." Can you show me how to make it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You do not pass value to radius in constructor so it is not initialized (0). So the if statement will always pass since 0 == 0 :). Pass

```
public Circle(double radius) // something like this
```

and assign it inside constructor to radius